# PHP - Faster way to use a do-while loop

Tags: php

I recently started a little project in PHP, I'm sort of new to this and this may be a beginner question but I can't find any help so I'm asking here.

I am working on a card game and I want to give up to six players random cards. I store how many cards everyone gets in $cardstoget and how many players there are in $player. I have an array $usedcards with values like [0] => 0, [1] => 0 and so on. I determine if the card is already used by putting it to 1 instead of 0 like this: [1] => 1. There are 80 cards and I plan on having [0] filled with the number of unused cards left.

I use this code:

```
for ($i = 1;$i <= $player;$i++) {
 for ($i2 = $cardstoget;$i2 > 0;$i2--) {
  do {
   $temp = mt_rand(1,80);
  } while ($usedcards[$temp] = 1);
  ${"cards".$i} = ${"cards".$i} . $temp;
  $usedcards[$temp] = 1;
 }
}
```

When I execute the code I get this error message:

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /var/www/create.php on line 47
```

So now to my question: How can I change the do-while loop to make it to something similar but faster? I know this loop is the problem, I tried it without and it worked fine,but I can't know it this card is already on someone's hand.

I hope somebody out there can help me and any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: `$temp = mt_rand(1,80);` made you do while unstoppable..

Comment: Can you explain that? Why? And how can I replace it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your immediate problem is the `$usedcards[$temp] = 1` condition. You're *assigning* `1` here, which results in the condition always being `true`, and the loop looping endlessly.

More generally, you'll want a deterministic algorithm, not one whose completion depends on randomness. Something like:

```
$cards = range(1, 80);
shuffle($cards);

for ($i = 0; $i < $cardsPerPlayer; $i++) {
    foreach ($players as &$player) {
        $player['cards'][] = array_shift($cards);
    }
    unset($player);
}
```

This mimics a real shuffling-and-distribution of cards as you'd do in a real game.

Comment: you only answered this question so you could `shuffle($cards);`.  :-)

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at it and let you guys know how it worked!

Comment: Somewhere there's a shell-related question with `$ got a light?` -> `No match.`

Comment: I don't understand how you user the foreach. Where does the $players come from? And player is only a number. Bur all these functions are great, I didn't know about them.

Comment: @Phil In the example I'm assuming `$players` is an array like `array(array('name' => 'Bob', 'cards' => array()), array('name' => 'Pete', 'cards' => array()), ...)`, which is a more logical data structure than plain numbers for this purpose. And you *really* should be using arrays, not `${"cards".$i}`.

Comment: Ah, okay. I'm writing the string of numbers in to a XML file, that's why I need it as one string. I got it to work, I used shuffle and array_shift in my code. Thank you for your help!